# Handling Case Insensitive Application name in the Url

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications, servlet-filters

I am Developing Java WebApplication which is hosted on Tomcat. I have the following Web application hosted on Tomcat:

Application Name: "Companies"

Accessing Url: http://192.28.123.20:8085/Companies

Now I could be able to access my "Companies" application using the Accessing Url but Now I want to access "Companies" webapp, If I enter any case i.e(companies, comPAnies, ComPaNIes, etc..).

I know that We can use "ROOT" to handle the above requirement, to do this I need to have one servlet filter in ROOT and Url mapping in "web.xml" like below:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>BaseFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>sample.context.filter.BaseFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>BaseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/companies</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/comPAnies</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ComPaNIes</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/companies/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/comPAnies/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ComPaNIes/</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

The above url-pattern mapping is to hit the Servlet filter in the ROOT folder, Like this I could get many combinations to
handle mixed case application name.

Could any body tell me, Am I following the proper way to handle requirement?
Please suggest me if any other way to handle this mixed case requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the context root of your application is /* you can set the filter mapping to /* and then when the filter is invoked you can do this:

```
if (request.getServletPath().toUpperCase().equals("COMPANIES") {
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/Companies").forward(request.response)
}
```

The catch is that for the filter to run the container must find a valid target for the inbound request. To be sure of this you can add a default servlet (servlet with a mapping of "/*"). If this servlet ever gets invoked forward the request to your welcome page.

Also note that the code snippet does not allow for any path info in the request, so if you need to allow for that, get the path info from request.getPathInfo() and add it to "/Companies" when you get the request dispatcher.

Comment: Since some back ground requests are going on, I can not use "/*"

Comment: So "Companies" is the context root?